# Generate a obfuscated JAR for code distribution

Tags: android, jar, obfuscation

I am working on an Android library project. I want to distribute this library as JAR to other developers.Before distributing the JAR I want to obfuscate it. I have tried using PROGUARD for this purpose, but its failing at the last step and says

`The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper '-keep' options?`

Can anyone suggest what is going wrong ?

=================EDIT : Error Log =======================

```
ProGuard, version 4.7
Reading program jar [C:\Users\XYZ\Downloads\login.jar]
Reading library jar [D:\Softwares\Android SDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\sdk\platforms\android-8\android.jar]
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI'
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI'
Note: the configuration refers to the unknown class 'javax.swing.JComponent'
Note: there were 3 references to unknown classes.
You should check your configuration for typos.
The output jar is empty. Did you specify the proper '-keep' options?
```

=============== Edit : proguard.cfg =====================

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keep public class MyClass extends MyView {

public static String GetSessionID () {
    }
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
   native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
   public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
   public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
   public static **[] values();
   public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
   public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your proguard file ?

Comment: Try out by adding `-dontwarn` in your proguard file.

Comment: Add like this `-keep class javax.swing.plaf.** { *; }` This should work.

Comment: Have you tried adding `-dontwarn` line in your file ?

Comment: yes.tried that also but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your proguard file.

```
 -keep class <your jar file name>.** { *; }
```

Comment: tried. Not working :( ... Also there is now class with the same name as my JAR's name

Comment: @Mayank Please show your proguard file and full error log. Which jar file you are using ?